# Fetching rows of 2 types

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a column Type in the database. I want to get all rows of type A and only first N rows of type B, both sorted by say DateCreated. Can I write a single query to do this? Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: please post the structure of your tables

Answer (score 3):

```
   SELECT *
     FROM tbl
    WHERE TYPE='A'
UNION ALL
   SELECT *
     FROM (
          SELECT TOP(N) *
            FROM tbl
           WHERE TYPE='B'
        ORDER BY DateCreated
      ) X
 ORDER BY DateCreated
```

Answer (score 2):

With the assumption that this is from one table with the following structure or similar:

```
[type] [nchar](10) NULL,
[date] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

(select * from [TableName] where [TableName].[type]='t1') 
union 
(select TOP 2* from [TableName]  where [TableName].[type]='t2') 
order by [date]desc
```

(Replace 'TOP2' with required results from the second type)

Comment: You should *almost* never.. use `TOP` without `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ:

```
db
    .Where(x => x.Type == "A")
    .Union(db
        .Where(x => x.Type == "B")
        .OrderBy(x => x.SomeField)
        .Take(N));
    .OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated);
```